# odbc connection string for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, odbc

I have a programm which contents oracleClient database all the queries and strings are written in oracle, i wanted to convert it to odbc for connecting IBM-DB2. I am getting problem as 'keyword not supported- 'provider', I also tried keyword 'Driver' but getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    1.   Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _ 
        "Dbq=" & Server.MapPath(".\db\db.mdb") & ";Uid=admin;Pwd=password;"

    2. "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog= Your_Database_Name;UserId=Your_Username;Password=Your_Password;" 

    3. "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\App1\Your_Database_Name.mdb; Jet OLEDB:System Database=c:\App1\Your_System_Database_Name.mdw"
```

or visit the folowing links

http://www.sqlstrings.com/SQL-Server-connection-strings.htm

http://www.sqlstrings.com/MS-Access-connection-strings.htm

http://www.sqlstrings.com/

Comment: connectionString="Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};Persist Security Info=True;UID=****;Data Source=***.***.*.***;Default Collection=****;Pwd=******

Comment: i am using this oledb string for another project and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;
```

or visit the link below

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Comment: i wanted to connect ibm db2 can i use odbc connection for it? and if possible then take a luk at my question which problem i am getting u will get it from there